# How do I get the data send by Ajax in Django?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I tried to get the data I send via Ajax with request.GET.get, but this does not work. Data is always None. I really appreciate any kind of help!

This is my jQuery/Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".jcf-select.jcf-unselectable").on('click', function(){
            var sel = $('#sort').children("option:selected").val();
            console.log(sel)

        $.ajax({
            url: '/filter-data',
            data: sel,
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(res){
                console.log(res);
                $("#filter_products").html(res.order);
            }
        });
        });
    });
```

This is my view:

```
def filter_data(request):
    if request.is_ajax:
        query = []
        data = request.GET.get('data')
    
        if data == "gpv":
            query = data.order_by("price_with_shipping")[:150]

        elif data == "gp":
            query = data.order_by("lowest_price")[:150]

        elif data == "lp":
            query = data.order_by("liter_price")[:150]

        elif data == "tz":
            query = data.order_by("-lowest_price")[:150]

        t = render_to_string('homepage/ajax-products.html', {'order': query})

        return JsonResponse({'order': t})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data must be an object in ajax.
for example:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/filter-data',
        data: {'key-data':sel},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(res){
            console.log(res);
            $("#filter_products").html(res.order);
        }
```

and in your django veiw:

```
data = request.GET.get('key-data')
```